# Metal shader not working as expected

Tags: swift, graphics, metal, vertex-shader

If I run the following vertex shader in Metal/Swift I get a nice rectangle on the screen:

```
vertex Vertex vertexShader(uint k [[ vertex_id ]],
                           device float2* position [[buffer(1)]]){
    Vertex output;
    float2 pos = position[k];
    output.position = float4(pos,0,1);
    return output;
};
//position [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
//indexList [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

Now if I run the following I get a blank screen:

```
vertex Vertex vertexShader(uint k [[ vertex_id ]],
                           device float3* position [[buffer(1)]]){
    Vertex output;
    float3 pos = position[k];
    output.position = float4(pos,1);
    return output;
};
//position [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
//indexList [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

It seems to me these should produce identical results. What am I missing?

Comment: Not experienced enough on shaders, so please understand! The differences are `float2` versus `float 3`, and how you declare `float4`. A couple of things come to mind. (1) Why are assets @1, @2, @3? I thought because of pixels. Are you somehow dealing with pixel density? You haven't mentioned the devices you've tested on.) (2) Using coreImage, the fourth dimension is generally "alpha". is your `float4(pos,1)` defaulting to an alpha or 0? Just trying to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you filling the buffer associated with index 1 in your app code?

I suspect you're just supplying an array of floats. Well, `float3` is not packed. Its layout is not the same as 3 `float`s. There's padding. Its size is actually the same as `float4` or 4 `float`s.

Probably, the simplest fix is to declare `position` as a pointer to `packed_float3`.